# Exclude image titles from search results

Tags: images, search, exclude

I would like to exclude image titles from search results. For instance, if I have an image called `image-wikipedia.jpg`, right now, if I search for `Wikipedia` the story that uses that image is returned in the results.

I tried the Simply Exclude plugin and Relevanssi plugin, but neither worked. I don't know if it's because I am using a custom search results page that these plugins aren't working.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!